# Pandas - Update/Merge 2 Dataframes based on multiple matching column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes `left_df` and `right-df`, which both have 20 columns with identical names and dtypes. `right_df` also has 2 additional columns with unique values on every row.

I want to update rows in `right_df` with ALL the values from `left_df` where the values in ALL columns in a list of a subset of columns, `matching_cols = ['col_1', 'col_3', 'col_10', 'col_12']` are identical in both dataframes. The values in the additional 2 unique columns in `right_df` should be preserved.

Ideally, I want to also drop those rows from `left_df` in the same command, or as the next command if this isn't possible. I need to do this process more than once, matching on several different lists of columns, with the `left_df` dropping matched rows each loop, until eventually no further matches are found.

An acceptable alternative would be any method to create a new dataframe `new_df` containing the set of rows where all specified columns in the list `matching_cols` match,  with values from `left_df` in the first 20 columns and values from `right_df` in the remaining 2 columns.

I don't care about preserving the indices at any point in either dataframe, I am importing them to SQL after this and will reindex them on one of the 2 `right_df` values at the end.

New to Pandas and can't determine what method to use, have tried variations of `.merge`, `.join`, `.update`, etc, but can't seem to specify to only update when my desired column values all match, or how to drop those rows/export them to a new df.

Update: Added pseudocode below:

For a `left_df` as:

```
left_df = pd.DataFrame({
   'col_0': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
   'col_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
   'col_2': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],
   'col_3': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],
   'col_4': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],
   'col_5': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],
   'col_6': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],
   'col_7': ['new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'],                
  })
```

and a right_df as:

```
right_df = pd.DataFrame({
   'col_0': ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
   'col_1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'X', 'E', 'F'],
   'col_2': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_3': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_4': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_5': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_6': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_7': ['old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old', 'old'],
   'col_8': ['uid_0', 'uid_1', 'uid_2', 'uid_3', 'uid_4', 'uid_5'],
   'col_9': ['uid_a', 'uid_b', 'uid_c', 'uid_d', 'uid_e', 'uid_f'],                
  })
```

Where `matching_cols = ['col_0', 'col_1']`

I want to get the following result either as a new dataframe or in-place on `right_df` (note that `col_1` doesn't match on row 3, so is not changed)

```
  col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7  col_8  col_9
0     0     A   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_0  uid_a
1     1     B   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_1  uid_b
2     2     C   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_2  uid_c
3     3     X   old   old   old   old   old   old  uid_3  uid_d
4     4     E   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_4  uid_e
5     5     F   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_5  uid_f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) and the Pandas documentation:

First, it's a `.merge` I need, and I specify the suffixes as `'_r'` for only the columns to be copied from the `right_df` / for the old values I'm updating:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, on=['col_0', 'col_1'], suffixes=(None, '_r'))
```

This yields a new dataframe with rows containing both the new and old columns, only for rows in each dataframe where the values in columns `on=['col_0', 'col_1']` are a match. Then I drop the "old" columns by using a regex filter on the text `'_r'`:

```
merged_df.drop(list(merged_df.filter(regex = '_r')), axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This yields a dataframe with only the "modified" rows and no unmodified rows, which is close enough for what I need.

```
  col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7  col_8  col_9
0     0     A   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_0  uid_a
1     1     B   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_1  uid_b
2     2     C   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_2  uid_c
3     4     E   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_4  uid_e
4     5     F   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_5  uid_f
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new_df=pd.concat([left_df,right_df.iloc[:,-1:-3]],axis=1)
```

Comment: in this, what's `.iloc[:,-1:-3]` referring to?

Comment: update: tried it, it works but this omits the 2 columns I need from `right_df` to be included in the result.

Comment: ```.iloc[:,-1:-3]``` is indexing of the columns in the dataframe if you need specific columns you can also try ```.loc[:,['list of columns seperated by commas in quotes']]```  this will surely solve everything

Comment: i just now saw the edit you made and what i think is ```above answer will do work (.loc) ``` since its the only correct way i could possibly think of concatinating the data ``` you have to specify the names correctly``` in loc .....do  try to remove the occurence of ```col_8``` twice in the data

Comment: ```new_df=pd.concat([left_df,right_df.loc[:,['col_0','col_1','col_8','col_9']],axis=1)```

Comment: Sorry, even after adding a missing bracket in what I THINK is the right spot, this yields a syntax error:   File "<ipython-input-12-307deaa2e0af>", line 1
    new_df=pd.concat([left_df,right_df.loc[:,['col_0','col_1','col_8','col_9']],axis=1])
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

Using your own solution:

> ```
> merged_df = pd.merge(left_df, right_df, on=['col_0', 'col_1'], suffixes=(None, '_r'))
> merged_df.drop(list(merged_df.filter(regex = '_r')), axis=1, inplace=True)
> ```

You can combine them to get the final goal:

```
mix_df = right_df.set_index(['col_0','col_1'])
mix_df[['col_2','col_3','col_4','col_5','col_6','col_7','col_8','col_9']] = merged_df.set_index(['col_0','col_1'])
final_df = mix_df.fillna(right_df.set_index(['col_0','col_1'])).reset_index()
```

Result (final_df):

```
  col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5 col_6 col_7  col_8  col_9
0     0     A   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_0  uid_a
1     1     B   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_1  uid_b
2     2     C   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_2  uid_c
3     3     X   old   old   old   old   old   old  uid_3  uid_d
4     4     E   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_4  uid_e
5     5     F   new   new   new   new   new   new  uid_5  uid_f
```