# Update Row of One DF (df1) based off matching columns between 2 dataframes (df1, df2)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes

DF1:

> ```
> EmployeeID CollectiveBargainingUnit BusinessGroup ProfitCenter Eligible
> 1          12A                      A12           UGZ.         
> 2          17A                      B12           MGZ.         
> 3          18A                      C12           DGZ.         
> 4          19A                      D12           XGZ.
> ```

DF2:

> ```
> CollectiveBargainingUnit BusinessGroup ProfitCenter Eligible
> 12A                      A12           UGZ.         True
> 17A                      B12           MGZ.         False
> 18A                      C12           DGZ.         False
> 19A                      D12           XGZ.         True
> 12A                      A13           UGZ.         False
> 27A                      C12           MKZ.         True
> 32A                      C22           DGZ.         True
> 19A                      D99           XGZ.         False
> ```

What would I would like to accomplish is this

> ```
> EmployeeID CollectiveBargainingUnit BusinessGroup ProfitCenter Eligible
> 1          12A                      A12           UGZ.         True
> 2          17A                      B12           MGZ.         False
> 3          18A                      C12           DGZ.         False
> 4          19A                      D12           XGZ.         True
> ```

Based off of multiple columns between the two Dataframes (CollectiveBargainingUnit BusinessGroup ProfitCenter) I'd like to access it's eligibility in DF2 and update it in DF1

Where I am left off is:

```
eligibility_map=df2.groupby(["BusinessGroup","ProfitCenter","CollectiveBargainingUnit"]).first()["Eligible"]

df1["Eligible"] = df1["BargainingUnit"].map(eligibility_map).fillna(df1["Eligible"])
```

I can't map it to only one column. I need to map to multiple columns at once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulate values in pandas DataFrame columns based on matching IDs from another DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44973255/manipulate-values-in-pandas-dataframe-columns-based-on-matching-ids-from-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `merge` `df1` with `df2` based on the required columns. Also, you have to drop `Eligible` in df1 before merging as it is not required.

```
(df1.drop('Eligible', axis=1)
 .merge(df2, on=['CollectiveBargainingUnit', 'BusinessGroup','ProfitCenter'], how='inner'))
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing. I actually just found the solution on another StackOverflow question which is exactly your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63347225/pandas-update-merge-2-dataframes-based-on-multiple-matching-column-values.   Thank you very, very much, ggaurav.